# Yacc/bison parsing: erroneous syntax error

Tags: ubuntu, parsing, bison, yacc

I have an errors vector (`static vector<string> errors;`) that keeps track of errors on a line thrown by `yyerror()`. These are printed after any lines in an input file which are also printed as the program parses. The relevant elements of my language are defined (in my parser.y file) as such:

```
statement_:
    statement ';' |
    error ';' ;
    
statement:
    expression |
    IF expression THEN statement_ ELSE statement_ ENDIF
    ;

expression:
    expression ANDOP relation |
    relation ;

relation:
    relation RELOP term |
    term;

term:
    term ADDOP factor |
    factor ;

factor:
    factor MULOP primary |
    primary ;

primary:
    '(' expression ')' |
    INT_LITERAL | 
    IDENTIFIER ;
```

where the capitalized tokens are their obvious equivalents in text. If those are relevant let me know and I'll add them.

I know this seems overly complicated, but for the purpose of this assignment, I'm not allowed to use %left or %right or any predefined precedence.

I'm trying to process the seemingly threadbare:

```
-- Conditional expression

function main returns integer;
begin
    if 5 + 4 >= 9 then
        6 + 9 * 3;
    else
        8 - 9 / 7;
    endif;
end;
```

but receiving the following error (running on VirtualBox Ubuntu 20.04.3):

[image: syntax error unexpected endif expecting semicolon]

I've tried changing my definition of the if statement many times, the only thing I could get to work was to remove the `ELSE statement_` bit and comment out that block in the input file. I simply don't understand why keeping this in there causes this error.

flex and bison versions:

[image: flex and bison versions]

Comment: Does the expression in the body of the `else` parse correctly as a statement? A good place to start debugging stuff like this is to enable [bison traces](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Tracing), which is quite easy to do (you just need to add one option to your bison invocation and make sure that the global `yydebug` is set to 1). That will show you where the state of the parser stack when the syntax error is triggered, and it will also show you all the tokens being passed into the parser, in case you have some bug in your lexer.

Comment: One thing to remember (I don't know if this is relevant because I can't see your code) is that if you don't call `yyerrok`, bison will suppress errors detected in the three tokens following error recovery. That sometimes hides clues which would be important. But tracing your parser is far more effective.